# React native firebase: save/retrieve collection reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

In my react native code, I'm loading a list of products from firebase firestore, from the products collection, when the app starts.
Every product contains a user id. I'm trying to get user information from the users collection for every product.

In other words, I'm trying to build a new array that contains products' information however I want to replace the user id document with user information object.

what is the best way to do that ?

```
const GetProductsByDate = () => {
    let products_list = []
    const userRef = firestore().collection('users')
    const productsRef = firestore()
        .collection('products')
        .orderBy('date_listed', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            products_list = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(async documentSnapshot => {
                products_list.push({
                    ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                    seller : awaituserRef.doc(documentSnapshot.data().seller.id).get().data(),
                    productId: documentSnapshot.id
                })
            })
            setProducts(products_list)
        })
        return() => {
            userRef
            productsRef
        }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is a typo and that there's actually a space in there: `awaituserRef`. Can you update the code if it indeed still is not working when you add the space?

Comment: No the space is fine in the code but seems I got the typo when I added the code here

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to set the updated list of products after you load each next user:

```
const productsRef = firestore()
    .collection('products')
    .orderBy('date_listed', 'desc')
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        products_list = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(async documentSnapshot => {
            const user = (await userRef.doc(documentSnapshot.data().seller.id).get()).data();
            products_list.push({
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                seller : user,
                productId: documentSnapshot.id
            })
            setProducts(products_list)
        })
    })
```

If you want to wait for all of them to load before showing any products, see [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) on how to use a `for of` loop rather than `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but one of the problems that I'm running into is 
userRef.doc(documentSnapshot.data().seller.id).get()).data()
it returns an error but when I replace data() with .then(snapData=>....)it works!